# Sending an object, in a get request, in params, in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, postman

I'm new here on the site, I opened this user a few days ago.

I want to send in a get object request, I do it through the postman.

I'm trying to do it, but it's not working for me, I probably have a little problem somewhere.

This is what I'm trying to do.

In postman:

[image]

Axios get request:

```
app.get('/realtimeConversations', FBAuth, getRealtime);
```

The function I run on the server side.

```
exports.getRealtime= (req, res) => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify("testing"));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query));
    console.log(req.query.user);
    console.log(req.query.user.uid_1);
    console.log(req.query.user.uid_2);

        return res.json([]);
}
```

i try to use JSON.parse instead but this is not working for me:\

```
exports.getRealtime= (req, res) => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify("testing"));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query));
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.user));
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.user).uid_1);
    console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.user).uid_2);

        return res.json([]);
}
```

I can get the object, but I can't access the values inside it

These are the prints I get on firebase:

[image]

Comment: Can you get `req.query.user`? I think this should be available, but the value of this might be string, so you'll have to `const user = JSON.parse(req.query.user)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes I manage to get the object, it comes back to me like this: `{"user":"{ uid_1: \"user.handle\", uid_2: \"userUid\" }"}`

Comment: i try to use the JSON.parse but this is not working for me, i got SyntaxError

Comment: I think that is because the keys of the json are not string (double quotes). Your query should be `user={ "uid_1": "user.handle", "uid_2": "userUid" }`

Answer (score 1):

**what you are using currently is :**

```
 { uid_1: "user.handle", uid_2: "userUid" }
```

here the key name which is a string is not enclosed with doublie quotes so its not a valid json and hence JSON.parse will fail.

**use query parameter as :**

```
{ "uid_1": "user.handle", "uid_2": "userUid" }
```

you can check this is in postman side itself .

**Try the below code in postman pre-request or test scrit**

```
  console.log(JSON.parse(pm.request.url.query.get("user")).uid_2)
```